# Integration with Multiple identity providers with Office 365

Tags: azure, office365, identity, okta, idp

I wanted to know whether i can integrate multiple IDPs with O365 suite. I have already integrated O365 with Azure. we need to have Okta integration with O365. i am not sure whether this is feasible